# Formating NSDate to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.XXX [gmt offset[:tz name]]

Tags: ios, timestamp, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to create a date looks like this:

```
19961005132200.124[-5:EST]
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
+ (NSString *)getDate {
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.000[ZZ:zzz]"];

    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [df setTimeZone:gmt];
    return [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

This is returning:

```
201604103050483.000[+0000:GMT]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Start by reading the docs for the date format specifiers. Case matters for each letter. Don't just make it all uppercase.

Comment: And why are you setting the date formatter's timezone to GMT when you appear to want the output to be in the local timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string uses the format patterns [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

So

```
- (NSString *)getDate {
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS[Z:z]"];

    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
    [df setTimeZone:gmt];
    return [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Output

```
20160412021134.302[-0500:EST]
```

**Option 2:**

```
- (NSString *)getDate {
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS[Z:z]"];

    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
    [df setTimeZone:gmt];

    NSString *date = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d+\\.\\d+\\[[+-]?)(0?)(\\d)(\\d{2})(.*)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    return [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:date options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, date.length) withTemplate:@"$1$3$5"];
}
```

Output:

```
20160412021134.302[-5:EST]
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by bookmarking the [Unicode specification for date format specifiers](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Then look at each of the parts you need:

- 4-digit year: yyyy
- 2-digit month: MM
- 2-digit day: dd
- 24-hour 2-digit hour: HH
- 2-digit minute: mm
- 2-digit second: ss
- 3-digit fractional second: SSS

There is a problem with the timezone since there is no specifier that will give you the part before the colon except with a leading zero. The closest you will get is: `x:z`.

Put all together you want: `yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS[x:z]`

```
+ (NSString *)getDate {
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS[x:z]"];

    return [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Do not set the formatter's timezone if you want the output to be in the user's local timezone.